# magento - how to show only configurable product in main category, simple product in sub-category

Tags: magento, categories, magento-1.8, configurable

I want to know how can I do this. I want to when i click main category, just show configurable product in page, and when i click sub-category, show simple product in page. Please help me in this, it will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check category level and then can display configurable product in it

```
 if($category->getLevel() == 2){
        $_productCollection1 = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable'); 

       foreach ($_productCollection1 as $product1) {
          echo $product1->getName();  
        }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: sorry but can you show me where is i put code. Thanks